# Why is StringIndexOutOfBounds Exception happening for this piece of code?

Tags: java

I wish to remove adjacent letters having the same value.

Like: abbcddaffa becomes ----> acddaffa ----> acaa ---->ac

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static String super_reduced_string(String s){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        for(int i = 0; i<sb.length(); i++){
            if(sb.charAt(i)==sb.charAt(i+1)){
                sb.delete(i,i+2);
                //System.out.println(sb.length());
                i =- 1;
            }
        }

        String resultString = sb.toString();
        return resultString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.next();
        String result = super_reduced_string(s);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

When I am adding this `i = -1` to the end of the loop in order to restart the loop, this StringIndexOutOfBounds Exception keeps happening. But then I need to restart the loop.

Comment: You're looping while `i < sb.length()`, so `i` will be `sb.length() - 1` on the last iteration. Character indexes in a StringBuffer are 0 through length - 1. You're doing `sb.charAt(i+1)`.

Comment: Rather than hacking your `for` loop to restart when you find a match, consider using a `while` loop instead. And when you're comparing adjacent characters, consider what happens at the end of the string. Which character do you compare the last letter of the string to? If `i` is the last character of the string, what is `i + 1`?

Comment: Oh yes thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
for(int i = 0; i<sb.length(); i++){
```

you looped `i` to `sb.length()`, so `i` will always be less than `sb.length()` inside the loop. This means that `i` will always be a valid index of the string builder. So far so good.

Then in the next line:

```
if(sb.charAt(i)==sb.charAt(i+1)){
```

You are checking the character at `i+1`! If this were the last iteration of the loop, `i` would be `sb.length() - 1`, and `i+1` would be `sb.length()`, which is not a valid index!

To fix this, simply loop until `i < sb.length() - 1`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<sb.length() - 1; i++){
```

Comment: Yes yes. Got it!. Thank You!

Comment: @AKronym if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark after a few minutes.